# Referees in Dota 2 matches

Tags: dota-2

Watching the International qualifiers, there are green named referees, talking to players about why they're pausing (and maybe other powers that aren't so visible, such as allowing a team that calls gg to end the game early?).

Is this a special Valve only feature, or is it possible to get it in "normal" games, or casual matches between two teams that'd like a referee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Finol pls]

Is this the kind of green colour you mean ?

If so, they are not necessary admins of the tournament but rather spectators directly in the lobby of the game played (unlike spectators from DotaTV who generally have delay), either as caster/cocaster or as specatators. They can speak to everyone in the game, pause it and most of the time an admin/organizer of the tournament will fill one of these slots to act as a referee in extreme cases but not always, for example in some small amateur tournaments where players have to report the game score themselves.

By the way their colour isn't always green, I believe it depends on the order they joined the lobby (their spectator slot).